# "The collection is inconsistent state" for multiple tests using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS but not while using Windows 10

Tags: nearprotocol

I have an issue running tests for the payments-contract demo https://github.com/near-apps/payments-contract running on ubuntu the error messages are as follows:

```
running 3 tests
test tests::make_deposit ... ok
test tests::make_deposit_and_payment ... thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: "The collection is an inconsistent state. Did previous smart contract execution terminate unexpectedly?" })', /home/simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/near-sdk-2.0.1/src/environment/mocked_blockchain.rs:165:54
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
FAILED
test tests::make_deposit_and_withdrawal ... thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: "The collection is an inconsistent state. Did previous smart contract execution terminate unexpectedly?" })', /home/simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/near-sdk-2.0.1/src/environment/mocked_blockchain.rs:165:54
FAILED
```

No matter which one is first it will successfully complete the test however any subsequent test/s will always fail.
Whereas when I run the same repo on Windows 10 all 3 tests work fine. I am using the same lib.rs file. **Do tests need to be cleared after each one completes?**

I noticed a similar question was answered by revising how the TreeMap is given an id in the contract. The only map I have is

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct PaymentContract {
    pub owner_id: AccountId,
    pub deposits: UnorderedMap<AccountId, Vec<Deposit>>,
}

impl Default for PaymentContract {
    fn default() -> Self {
        panic!("Should be initialized before usage")
    }
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl PaymentContract {
    #[init]
    pub fn new(owner_id: AccountId) -> Self {
        assert!(env::is_valid_account_id(owner_id.as_bytes()), "Invalid owner account");
        assert!(!env::state_exists(), "Already initialized");
        Self {
            owner_id,
            deposits: UnorderedMap::new(b"deposits".to_vec()),
        }
    }
```

Testing looks like below

```
// use the attribute below for unit tests
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::convert::TryFrom;
    use near_sdk::MockedBlockchain;
    use near_sdk::{testing_env, VMContext};
    
    fn ntoy(near_amount: u128) -> U128 {
        U128(near_amount * 10u128.pow(24))
    }

    fn get_context() -> VMContext {
        VMContext {
            predecessor_account_id: "alice.testnet".to_string(),
            current_account_id: "alice.testnet".to_string(),
            signer_account_id: "bob.testnet".to_string(),
            signer_account_pk: vec![0],
            input: vec![],
            block_index: 0,
            block_timestamp: 0,
            account_balance: 0,
            account_locked_balance: 0,
            attached_deposit: 0,
            prepaid_gas: 10u64.pow(18),
            random_seed: vec![0, 1, 2],
            is_view: false,
            output_data_receivers: vec![],
            epoch_height: 19,
            storage_usage: 1000
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn make_deposit() {
        let mut context = get_context();
        context.attached_deposit = ntoy(1).into();
        testing_env!(context.clone());

        let mut contract = PaymentContract::new(context.current_account_id.clone());
        contract.deposit("take my money".to_string());

        let deposits = contract.get_deposits(context.signer_account_id.clone());


        assert_eq!(deposits.get(0).unwrap().memo, "take my money".to_string());
    }

    #[test]
    fn make_deposit_and_payment() {
        let mut context = get_context();
        context.attached_deposit = ntoy(1).into();
        testing_env!(context.clone());

        let mut contract = PaymentContract::new(context.current_account_id.clone());
        contract.deposit("take my money".to_string());
        contract.make_payment(0);

        let deposits = contract.get_deposits(context.signer_account_id.clone());

        assert_eq!(deposits[0].paid, true);
    }

    #[test]
    fn make_deposit_and_withdrawal() {
        let mut context = get_context();
        context.attached_deposit = ntoy(1).into();
        testing_env!(context.clone());

        let mut contract = PaymentContract::new(context.current_account_id.clone());
        contract.deposit("take my money".to_string());
        contract.withdraw(0);

        let deposits = contract.get_deposits(context.signer_account_id.clone());

        assert_eq!(deposits.len(), 0);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think the problem might be related with rust executing tests in parallel (maybe this is not the default on windows, or with the tool you are using). From the error it seems to be that all tests are trying to interact with the same account at the same time. Try to test this hypothesis using `cargo test -- --test-threads 1`. Also it is a good idea to open an issue in the relevant repository.